# Did Esurance put up a billboard saying "Cover your home in a dick"?

Tags: advertising, photography

[This tweet has been making the rounds](https://twitter.com/theorosendorf/status/507230080557662208) about the dangers of bad [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning):

[image: "Cover your home in a click" advertisement]

Supposedly the letters "c" and "l" are run together so that "click" looks like "dick" instead.

I call shenanigans. Surely *someone* noticed the problem while the sign was going up? Has the image of the sign been modified from the original? Or is this an optical illusion?

Comment: A bit OT but the blue tag line had me choking on my coffee.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet it's supposed to be "click"

Comment: that's what bad kerning will do for your billboards

Comment: If it's the kind of billboard poster that's actually many smaller sheets glued next to each other, it's possible that the "c" and "l" were either side of a join and the person who put this particular billboard up accidentally (or deliberately) placed them with too much overlap.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It appears to be a single sheet of canvas. I actually found [a video of a similar esurance billboard being installed](https://vine.co/v/M22VDeadL01) in the same location, but the text is different (suggesting either that this picture is fake or, perhaps more likely, simply that esurance has run multiple ads in this same location).

Comment: @ratchetfreak Ahh... [F*ck Yeah Keming](http://fuckyeahkeming.com).  `click` is a particularly problematic word.

Comment: As always, [XKCD has the answer](http://i.imgur.com/078Gp9f.png).

Comment: @UweKeim XKCD page with tooltip: [Kerning](http://xkcd.com/1015/)

Comment: It looks to me like the baseline of "ick" does not line up with the baseline of "cover your home in a". That strongly suggests it was photoshopped.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The image was stated to [have been photoshopped](http://theconcourse.deadspin.com/heres-a-big-billboard-that-says-dick-in-downtown-chicag-1630274958).

> UPDATE: Welp, the fun's over. Esurance contacted us today, and they're saying the image above is photoshopped. To be fair, we were incredulous when we first saw the photo, but decided to roll with it when we saw Esurance addressed the lady who first tweeted out the above image, and said they'd removed the billboard.

[image]

Comment: Hm, so I wonder why Esurance's initial tweet appeared to confirm that the problem existed?  Or were they being sly - if no billboards were affected, then "we have removed all affected billboards" would be vacuously true.

Comment: @NateEldredge Extra publicity for free?

Answer (score 30):

It's real and was confirmed by esurance in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/esurance/status/507219093922279425).

Just in case the tweet gets removed later, here is a screenshot:

[image]

According to several sources online, the billboard was put in Chicago, not in New York:

[redeye Chicago](http://www.redeyechicago.com/news/local/redeye-esurance-removes-chicago-billboards-with-nsfw-typo-20140903,0,7334907.story)

> Esurance removes Chicago billboards with NSFW typo

[A blog post](http://theconcourse.deadspin.com/heres-a-big-billboard-that-says-dick-in-downtown-chicag-1630274958)

> Here's A Big Billboard That Says Dick In Downtown Chicago

Comment: Even with the apparently confirming reply, I'm still a bit skeptical. Given the how many people carry cellphone cameras around these days, and how obvious the mistake is (it doesn't just *sort of look like* it says "dick" if you squint at it, it *actually*, unambiguously, says "dick"), surely there should be more than one photo of that billboard.

Comment: Definitely Chicago. The billboard in the picture is mounted on the "bridge" that is train yard behind the Metra station at Madison and Canal.

Comment: sounds like a clever marketing trick if you ask me.

Comment: [Evidently not, eh?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/23107/20688)

Comment: In Chicago, I'm inclined to think the photoshopped version is less NSFW than the original.

Comment: In light of the evidence in the accepted answer, this answer should be considered incorrect.